# Change ONLY the higher bit in MASM32

Tags: x86, bit-manipulation, masm

How can I change only the higher bit of byte in masm32? Assume I have `00101111` byte and want to get `10101111`.

Comment: Use `or` if you want to set the bit, or `xor` if you want to invert it.

Comment: @Michael, I want to set the bit. Could you provide more detailed explanation, please?

Comment: `or al, 80h` or something like that should suffice. You really should read up on [bitwise operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation) since they are very commonly used in assembly code.

Comment: @Michael, oh, I see. Thank you!

Comment: x86 has an instructions for each of the C bitwise operators so IMO this is a duplicate.